# How can I list the all Discord servers ID where my bot are in the console? | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I tried on googling but all of the errors was "is not a function", that's because i'm using discord.js V12?
I can't find it on google, there is less question about this one. This was my code.

```
var serverArray = client.guilds.array();
for(i = 0; i < serverArray.length; i++) {
    console.log("Server ID: " + serverArray[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
  console.log(`${guild.name} | ${guild.id}`);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let clientguilds = client.guilds.cache()
console.log(clientguilds.map(g => g.id) || "None")
```

This should do the trick! It's going to cache all the guilds your bot is in and then it will map the guilds as an array. We then get the id of each guild or, if it's not in any guilds "none".